# ¿Cómo convertir una fecha /Date(1577854800000)/ formato dd-MM-yyyy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

En mi ***datatable Jquery*** obtengo una fecha con este formato  /Date(1577854800000)/  desde  .net c# ***datetime*** y quiero convertirlo a este formato dd-MM-yyyy en mi datatable.

En punto

Estoy listando el campo fecha de la siguiente  manera desde .net el campo es de tipo datetime

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"].ToString())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si estas usando Datatables por lo que pones al principio o estas usando una tabla. Si es el caso de que usas Datatables, en la documentación explican como formatear una fecha, pero te dejo un ejemplo. Primero declaras las columnas y despues les das el formato de la siguiente manera:

```
        "columns": [
            { data: "FechaModificacion" }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0, render: function (data) {
                    return moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY | HH:mm');
                }
            }
        ],
```

El columnDefs sirve para eso. En targets apuntas a la columna que quieras y luego usas la api Momentjs que sirve para formatear fechas usando las funciones que te da.

Si lo que queres es hacerlo en una tabla común, que significaría que entendí mal al principio, podrías usar JQuery. Tendrías usar una función como esta:

```
function fixFecha(fecha) {
if (fecha == null) {
    return '';
}
else {
    var codigo_fecha = parseInt(fecha.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
    var fecha1 = new Date(codigo_fecha).toLocaleDateString("es-AR");
    var fecha_formato = $.format.date(fecha1, "dd-MM-yyyy");

    return fecha_formato;
}
```

}

Comment: para usar moment tienes que añadir la librería moment.js. Pero ten cuidado, es una librería poderosa pero de cuidado, sobre todo si trabajas con tiempo de varios países, horario de inverno/verano, etc...

Comment: Excelente con la librería moment.js funciono

Answer (score 0):

La fecha contenido en un json tiene esa representación.

La solución más rápida es que desde el controllador mandes tu fecha en [cadena ya formateada.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```
fecha = fecha.toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Y la otra opcón es formatear tu fecha desde el frontend cuando la vayas a mostrar.

```
String.prototype.toDate = function () {
    var date = this;
    if (!date)
        return "";
    var f = new Date(parseInt(date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10)),
        dia = f.getDate(), mes = (parseInt(f.getMonth()) + 1), anio = f.getFullYear();
    return ((dia < 10 ? "0" + dia : dia) + "/" + (mes < 10 ? "0" + mes : mes) + "/" + anio);
 }
```

Prefiero [definirla desde el string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392062/4068497) para que sea facil de llamar.

```
dr["fecha"].toDate()
```